# How to load cusomer model by token

Tags: customer, crud

is it possible to load customer model using only token?

One of my method generate a token this way:

```
$token = Mage::helper('customer')->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
            $customer->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($token);
```

and my second method takes this token in argument. Based on that i have to get customer model beacuse i want to change his password.

Comment: According to your code, you should already have the customer stored in the `$customer` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After rereading your post, I reckon the only way of doing it by using collection:

```
$customerCol = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')->addFieldToFilter('rp_token',$token)->setPageSize(1);

$customer = $customerCol->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: Could you explain me why it is necessary to call setPageSize method?